Why is this sufficient for continuity?
I don't understand why the following argument suffices for continuity in the proof of the following statement:
Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces and consider $\mathscr{C}(Y,X) := \{ f: Y \rightarrow X: \text{ $f$ is continuous.}\}$. We want to show that for $Y$ locally compact, we want to show that the evaluation map $$ \mathrm{e}: (f,y) \in  \mathscr{C}(Y,X) \times Y  \mapsto f(y) \in X$$ is continuous. Where the topologyy on $\mathscr{C}(Y,X)$ is the one induced by compact-open set toplogy (ie. induced by the subbasic set of $S(K,U)  = \{ f : f(K) \subset U \text{, where $K$ compact and $U$ open.} \}$).
My understanding of "subbasic" is that by taking all possible finite intersections of $S(K,U)$ for different $K$ and $U$'s we obtain a basis for the topology.
Now, the proof goes as follows:
Let $U \subset X$ open, thus we have $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (by continuity) for any $f \in \mathscr{C}(Y,X)$. For $y \in f^{-1}(U)$ there exists (by local compactness) a $K \subset f^{-1}(U)$ with $y \in K$. Therefore $f(K) \subset U$ and we see that $f \in S(K,U)$ and $y \in K \implies S(K,U) \times K$ is a neighborhood of $(f,y)$ contained in $\mathrm{e}^{-1}(U) \implies \mathrm{e}$ is continuous.
Why can we conclude that $e$ is continuous from that? We have show that for every open $U$ in $X$ the points in its preimage have a neighbordhood of the form $S(K,U) \times K$.

If $(f,y)\in\mathrm{e}^{-1}(U)$, then $S(K,U)\times K$ is a neighborhood of $(f,y)$ contained in ${e}^{-1}(U)$. Therefore, $\mathrm{e}^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of each of its points, and so it is an open set.
Having said this, it is clear to me that, in that proof, $S(K,Y)$ is a typo; it should be $S(K,U)$.

I think you meant "$e^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of each of its points".

@QuartelQuartz Yes. I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Thanks for pointing out the typo! I see. My brain had trouble bridging the gap from "Set is neighborhood of each of its points" to "it is open".

In case "If $U$ is a neighborhood of each of its points, then it is open" isn't obvious to anyone reading, I'd prove it as follows: Suppose $U$ isn't open but is a neighborhood of each of its points. Then there is $p \in U\setminus U^\circ$ and by assumption that $U$ is a neighborhood there must be an open $V \subset U, p \in V$. By construction we have $U^\circ \subsetneq V \subset U$ contradicting the definition of $U^\circ$ (largest open set in $U$). Thus proving our claim.
